# Новое окно при нажатии кнопки в Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

Создаю приложение-викторину на kivy. После разработки главного экрана возникла проблема - я не знаю как сделать второе окно. То есть, при нажатии кнопки старт должно появляться окно первого уровня, но я понятия не имею как это сделать.

Вот код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from  kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
Window.fullscreen = 'auto'

Builder.load_string("""

<Container>:
    Label: #заголовок
        text: '[i]very [color=FF0000][b]easy[/b][/color] 100 questions[/i]'
        markup: True
        ellipsis_options: {'color':(1,0.5,0.5,1),'underline':True}
        font_size: '25sp'
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'center'
        valign: 'middle'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y': 0.7 }
    Button: #кнопка посредине
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.28}
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.07
        text: 'Настройки'
        on_press: None

    Button: #кнопка снизу
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.07
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.17}
        text: 'Об авторе'
        on_press: None
    Button: #кнопка сверху
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.07
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.39}
        text: 'Начать игру'
        on_release: None

                  

    Button:
        text: "Оцените игру!"
        size_hint: 0.35, 0.06
        pos_hint: {'right':1}
        on_release: None

""")
class Container(FloatLayout):
   pass


class LesApp(App):
    def build(self):

      return Container()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    LesApp().run()
```